# Hausdorff maximal principle and Zermelo's fixed point theorem

Tags: order-theory, axiom-of-choice, fixed-point-theorems

Let's recall the Hausdorff maximal principle (**HPM**) and the Zemelo fixed point theorem (**ZFPT**):

**HPM**:  Every partially ordered set has a maximal chain.

**ZFPT**: Let $P$ be a partial order set in which every chain has a supremum and $f:P\to P$ such that $x\le f(x)$ for all $x\in P$. Then $f$ has a fixed point.

It is known from  Dunford, Schwartz (Linear operators) that **ZFPT** implies **HP**, and my question if the converse holds too ?

Hint: let $C$ be a maximal chain such that $\alpha=\sup(C)$, the we have $\alpha\le f(\alpha)$. Hence, $C\cup\{f(\alpha)\}$ is a chain, so by maximality of the chain $C$, we should have $f(\alpha)\in C$ and $f(\alpha)\ge \sup(C)$, which implies $f(\alpha)=\alpha$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. And yes, your proof is correct.

From the Hausdorff Maximality Principle, we get a maximal chain; from the assumption on upper bounds, this chain has a supremum $x$, which now has to be a maximal element of the partial order. But this means that $f(x)=x$ by maximality.

Comment: And all 2 are equivalent to AC? Probably..

Comment: Since Hausdorff's principle is equivalent to Zorn's lemma, I'd guess that the answer is yes. :P

Comment: Don't Dunford and Schwartz use choice in their proof of ZFPT => HPM? Their proof: If the set $\mathcal{E}$ of chains in $P$ has no maximal element, then there is a function $f \colon \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E}$ such that $A \subsetneq f(A)$, in contradiction with ZFPT. But the existence of $f$ requires choice, no? Moschovakis also gives a proof of ZFPT, without using choice as far as I can tell.